# How to update an entry in a list using c#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to update one of the entries on my list using the code below, but still no luck.

```
entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.Equals(fName))] = fNameNew;
```

I got an error on my parameter `fNameNew` and it says that I cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to x.PhonebookItem.

Comment: what is the value of fNameNew , and what are the properties of phonebookitem?

Comment: var fNameNew = Console.Readline();

PhonebookItem has firstname, lastname and number.

Comment: It would seem that `PhonebookList` is not a list of strings, but a list of some object you defined called `PhonebookItem`.

Comment: Should do like this : `entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))] = fNameNew;`. I am assuming FirstName is property in PhoneBook instance

Comment: I have public string FirstName {get; set; } , public string LastName {get; set;} and public string PhoneNumber {get; set; } in my PhonebookItem class

Comment: put the declaration code of `PhonebookItem` in your question please

Comment: still getting the same error after changing it to ab.FirstName.Equals

Comment: public class PhonebookItem
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign fNameNew to the firstname property of the object, so it should be

```
entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))].firstname = fNameNew;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be like `ab.FirstName.Equals(fName)`?

Comment: You guys are really amazing. its now working. Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
entries
.PhonebookList[
     entries
     .PhonebookList
     .FindIndex(ab => 
        ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))
].FirstName= fNameNew;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

First, you're trying to compare an entire object to a single string:

```
entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.Equals(fName))
```

You want to compare just one *property* on that object to the string:

```
entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))
```

At that point you're successfully referencing an object in the list:

```
entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))]
```

But the second problem is that you can't set *that entire object* to a string.  Instead, just set the property:

```
entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))].FirstName = fNameNew;
```

Comment: This one works. entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))].FirstName = fNameNew;

Answer (score 0):

FOr those who answer this question. Thank you very much. The code below works for me.

```
entries.PhonebookList[entries.PhonebookList.FindIndex(ab => ab.FirstName.Equals(fName))].FirstName = fNameNew;
```

Have a blessed day to all :) You guys are really amazing. :)

Comment: You have already accepted answer, dont need to post the same here